# c# Excel add-in Conditional Loading

Tags: excel, vsto, add-in, ribbon

I developed an Excel-Addin using Microsoft VS 2012 and VSTO.

The Ribbon property "StartFromScratch" is set to True, in order to hide default Excel Ribbon Tabs.

The problem is that this "StartFromScratch" is permanent. i.e. even if the user wants to use Excel normally without utilizing the add-in functionality, the add-in is loaded and hides the default Excel Tabs.

is there a way to load the Add-in conditionally? i.e. create a WinForms application that call the Excel application with specific parameter/argument in order to indicate whether to load the Add-in or not.

Thank you for your help

Comment: not sure if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/16170688/578738

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to load the Add-in conditionally?

Yes, there is. You can set the LoadBehavior key in the windows registry to prevent the add-in from loading when the host application starts. See [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) for more information. For example, you can use the 1 or 8 value which stands for :

*The application does not try to load the add-in automatically. The user can try to manually load the add-in, or the add-in can be loaded programmatically*.

Then when you need to load the add-in programmatically you can find the COMAddin instance in the COMAddIns collection (see the corresponding property of the Application class) and set the [Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.comaddin.connect.aspx) property which returns or sets the state of the connection for the specified COMAddIn object.

Also you may consider disabling all the UI functionality and event handlers. When required, you may give a signal to the add-in programmatically to re-enable itself. For example, see [Walkthrough: Calling Code in an Application-Level Add-in from VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Finally, you can read more about the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I already know about the LoadBehavior, however this will require the user to have "administrative" privileges on the machine in order for my application to set the registry value . is there any alternative?

Comment: Also you may consider disabling all the UI functionality and event handlers. When required, you may give a signal to the add-in programmatically to re-enable itself. For example, see [Walkthrough: Calling Code in an Application-Level Add-in from VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The add-in can load programmatically as per Eugene answer. Is there a way to set "StartFromScratch" property of the add-in programmatically?

Comment: Nope. You need to use ribbon xml to specify that property.

Comment: Actually, After some work I was able to do it. It's a turn-around but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

open your Ribbon Properties and set the `StartFromScratch = true;`

Then open up your Ribbon.Designer.cs
search for
    `this.StartFromScratch = true;`

replace it by 
    `this.StartFromScratch = System.IO.File.Exists(@System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\whateverFile.xyz");`

create another Exe file, that upon called, creates and empty whateverFile.xyz and then launches Excel.

Keep in mind that this exe has to remain running, and when the Excel quits, the file whateverFile.xyz has to be deleted by the exe, in order to disable the FullScreen property of the add-in.

Note that if you change the structure of the Ribbon, the StartFromScratch is reset to False, so it has to be re-modified.